# How to include socket.io script in my HTML page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, socket.io

I am trying to use `socket.io` at my `node.js` but having trouble setting it up.

I installed the `socket.io` node module for my node by:

```
npm install socket.io
```

My node is working perfectly and I am getting the message `info  - socket.io started` at node start. My `socket` at node listens to the same port as my `http` server on node. But the problem is with setting up the client system.

All the tutorials I have referred on the internet work under the assumption that my client file and node file (i.e. `html` file and node.js file) are in the same directory and simply include `socket.io` script in the html by:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

But the system that I am setting up will have separate directories for node and client namely `nodejs` and `web` (I am using NGINX as my websocket). My `socket.io` node module is inside `node_modules` directory under `nodejs` directory. Now how do I include the `socket.io` script in my client html? Should I copy my `socket.io` node module files in my `web` folder as well?

Comment: copy/past socket.io.js in your web/javascript/ folder <-- facing this issue that's what I did. It's working.

Comment: only the socket.io.js file or the whole folder?